# Datatables, BS4 and Borders

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-4

I want to remove the border lines between rows and cols in a jQuery DataTable but nothing seems to affect these lines.  I've tried all the BS table options I can think of and also many styling options.  Nothing seems to affect the lines.  The row divider lines appear to be double and column separator lines are fairly wide.  My basic question is: will anything affect the DataTable border lines or is this just baked into Datatables?

I'm using these references:

```
   <link href="~/lib/bootstrap4/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/lib/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap4/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
```

My Table classes are:

```
 class="table table-striped"
```

My Head class is:

```
<thead class="table-inverse" >
```

Nothing else in the table is classed or styled it's a simple 5 col table populated in a Core MVC EF project.  The Javascript is:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-table').DataTable({
            "searching": false,
            "pageLength": 25,
            "info": false,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "renderer": "dataTables.bootstrap4",
            "columns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { "orderable": false },
                { "orderable": false }
            ]
        });
    });
```

I've tried all sorts of "renderer" options - including not using it.  I've tried many style variations of border:none or border collapsed or border lines of 0px, border line color, etc.  Nothing seems to impact that aspect of the DataTable.  However, the BS stripe class and the inverse header class work as expected.

I feel the table looks ugly with the lines and want to get rid of them or mute their appearance.  I'm using BS4 everywhere else so want to stick with that. Any suggestions - thanks

Comment: Bootstrap 4 doensn't add any borders: http://www.codeply.com/go/4MCVg9nd4y, unless using `table-bordered` so it must be added by DataTables

Comment: @ZimSystem, Yes, I'm sure the borders are added by DataTables.  I'm wondering if there is any way I can cause datatables to stop doing that? I can't find anything in their docs - but, maybe someone knows a clever way around this?  Thanks for checking.

Comment: Hi, please, check the following link: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

A temporary fix for DataTable 1.10.16 is to add `cellspacing="0"` to your `<table>`

For example

```
<table id="example" class="table" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0">
```

This will be fixed in the next release of DataTable see [commit 2b0dce5b4e...](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/commit/2b0dce5b4e285e9c09b9c59293df363e99fffc76)